# Regex in scala to remove substring from string in dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am very much new to scala and need to remove sub-string from string in dataframe's column:

So dataframe looks like :

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "MAT - bat"),
  (64, "MDT - mouse"),
  (0,   "MAT - abc")
).toDF("number", "word")
```

and i need to remove  "MAT - ", "MDT - " from the word column and need to get the resultant dataframe as :

```
    |number| word|
    +------+-----+
    |     8|  bat|
    |    64|mouse|
    |     0|  abc|
    +------+-----+
```

can anyone please help me to get this .I am just trying to make it with the help of `"\\AM[a-zA-Z]T - "`

But nothing is working !!

Answer (score 2):

You can extract only small catheter words - `"[a-z]+"`. or 
You can replace Capital letters, space and "\"  - `"[A-Z]+\s+-" or "^M.+T\s-"`

```
scala> someDF.withColumn("word",regexp_replace(col("word"),"[A-Z]+\\s+-",""))
scala> res0.show
+------+------+
|number|  word|
+------+------+
|     8|   bat|
|    64| mouse|
|     0|   abc|
+------+------+
```

Comment: but it will all occurrence.I just need to remove the first occurrence.For e.g if the column contains values like "MAT - SHELF -X" then current regex_replace will give the result "X".
However,I need "SHELF -X"

Comment: Please use this- "^M.+T\\s-"